# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on external disks from an active workstation?

Tags: system-installation, external-hdd, disk, clone

I am running Ubuntu on my workstation and have connected three blank drives to it. I would like to install three copies of Ubuntu onto the blank drives while continuing to work in my operating system.

Essentially I'd like to write a 'base image' of Ubuntu to the blank disks, so that I can then place them into waiting workstations and power them on. I would expect most hardware to be autodetected upon boot, and I would also expect to be prompted to create a user account and set the hostnames on each one.

In the Windows world this would be called "Writing a WIM" to a disk using a tool such as [ImageX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

So I found [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installing_on_external_or_RAID_hard_disks) and the last item in this section looked promising, but the [resulting link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromImageLoadedOnHardDrive) is very dubious (suggesting to use Unetbootin and 'crossing fingers') and the result is to still manually run the installer if the finger-crossing incantation was effective :-/

Is there a documented method to fully extract the base system image onto a waiting disk so that it just boots up and runs? I suppose what I am asking for is similar to downloading a pre-built virtual machine and dumping it onto a physical disk.

If anyone is familiar with the [FOG Project](http://www.fogproject.org/), I suppose what I'm asking for is to do what they do with Windows, but with Linux (although I'd prefer to just extract the image from an official ISO rather than deploying it and capturing the partition.)

Comment: This will boot an ISO from a hard drive or any second drive
ISO Booting with Grub 2 from Hard drive - drs305
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot
Examples - you may copy & edit for your path & ISO version
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples

Comment: Thanks for the resources but this seems to be a way to manually edit my running grub menu entries, and doesn't address the question of how to put an image onto an external harddrive.

Comment: You just copy ISO into a folder and from grub can boot the ISO directly from internal hard drive. Then you can use that to install to external drive using Something Else install option. Do not use any auto install options.

Comment: I must not have been clear enough in the original question. I do not want to reboot my system. I want to attach an external drive to my running desktop and 'lay down an image' of a generic Ubuntu install. In fact, it would be nice to be able to attach multiple external drives to my system and simultaneously lay down three vanilla Ubuntu installs. I could then take those three drives and install them in new hardware and turn them on and enter user credentials and hostnames.For reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: What you want is [create an OEM install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview)  master disk. Then clone that disk, and put them in other computers.  One caveat, all the computers must have hardware that have open-source drivers that are already a part of the Ubuntu kernel. Or if they have hardware that needs proprietary drivers, it must be the same hardware, so that when you create the master disk, it includes the needed driver(s).

Comment: This is good. I'm not too worried about the driver issue as the kernel usually handles most of the hardware I encounter without a hiccup (way to go, Linus!). What about different sized hard drives? Perhaps Partclone can handle that. Thanks user68186!